System freeezes with newer kernels - works in recovery mode
Problem on T410 Intel Core i5 M520 after reinstalling the latest Ubuntu LTS version, 24.04, from the previous LTS version. I have also tried upgrading to 24.10 but with no success.
Selecting the recovery mode option in Grub prevents the freezing, leading me to believe it may be a sound or video driver issue in the latest kernels. I do get a start-up sound, but the volume keys don't work anymore. I have tried the latest stable release, 6.12.1, and 6.11.0-9.9, 6.8.1—but none work correctly.
I found that the system would freeze as soon as I opened Firefox browser.
Moving back to 6.5.1 kernel seems to prevent the issue, I'll try to find which kernel update point causes the issue. I am not sure how to deal with updates in the future unless this bug/config gets fixed.
Happy to provide any requested info but not the most proficient Ubuntu user so will need some guidance.

Kernel 6.7.6 works but 6.7.7 fails
